# Let $X\sim \operatorname{Poi}(\lambda)$ and $Y\sim \operatorname{Poi}(\mu)$, find $P(X>0|X+Y)$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

Let $X\sim \operatorname{Poi}(\lambda)$ and $Y\sim \operatorname{Poi}(\mu)$, find $P(X>0|X+Y)$.

**My attempt**

We have $P(X>0|X+Y)=\frac{P(\{X>0\}\cap \{X+Y=k\})}{P(X+Y=k)}$. What is $\{X>0\}\cap \{X+Y=k\}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the probability in your title does not make sense, you should be conditioning on $X+Y=k$ which I guess is what you are getting at with your attempt. If $X,Y$ are independent then $X+Y \sim \text{Poisson}(\lambda + \mu)$ and

\begin{align*}
P(X>0|X+Y=k) 
&= 1-P(X=0|X+Y=k) \\
&= 1 - \frac{P(X=0, X+Y=k)}{P(X+Y=k)}\\
&= 1 - \frac{P(X=0, Y=k)}{P(X+Y=k)}\\
&= 1 - \frac{P(X=0)P(Y=k)}{P(X+Y=k)}\\
&= 1 - \frac{e^{-\lambda} \frac{\mu^k e^{-\mu}}{k!} }{\frac{(\lambda+\mu)^k e^{-\mu-\lambda}}{k!}}\\
&= 1- \left ( \frac{\mu}{\lambda+\mu}\right)^k
\end{align*}

Comment: What about this thread? That's where I got the question from. I think your approach is more plausible. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3117750/question-on-two-independent-random-variables-under-poisson-distribution?noredirect=1

Comment: @Analysis I've answered your question already.. if you have a follow up you can post a new one and I'll be happy to help with it

Comment: Part of it is the same question as mine but with a different answer.

Comment: @Analysis no it isn't, the two answers are identical for the choice of 'k=0' in their notation.

Comment: sorry, missed that.